# Keras save model and load model changing shape of predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras

I want to save a `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier`. I used the model.save method as Keras recommends but when I load my model the model is a `keras.models.Sequential` instead of a `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier.`

This is a problem because when I want to make the prediction I have an output with this shape:

```
array([[0.21577413, 0.37268943, 0.13626885, 0.2752676 ],
       [0.22569732, 0.34428614, 0.15705906, 0.2729574 ],
       [0.24492404, 0.27987108, 0.21357943, 0.2616254 ],
       [0.24831992, 0.26592442, 0.22779736, 0.25795835],
       [0.24938227, 0.26125908, 0.23273101, 0.25662765]], dtype=float32)
```

Instead of this output that I want it

```
array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64)
```

So my question is, how could I save and load the keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier? Maybe is there another problem that is changing the output' shape of my predictions?

Thanks

Comment: Try joblib or pickle on KerasClassifier. `save()` will only save the underlying Sequential model.

Comment: @VivekKumar I tried before with joblib and It outputs the next error `can't pickle SwigPyObject objects` and Keras does not recommends to use Pickle. So any ideas?

Comment: Please show the code how you are saving and loading now and how you are calling the predictions. If you are using the `Sequential.predict()` I think it will return probabilities. You can change that to return only the predicted class.